# Youtube API not returning a video is live even when it is?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, httprequest

So I'm getting unintended behavior from the youtube api -

```
class youtube:
        def __init__(self):
            #self.youtube= YoutubeAPI('AIzaSyCoCdD-vL2zNIlQvNARXKXltqKIXcNJ6MA')
            self.api_key=my_number


        def channel_id(self,name):
            string= "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=" + self.api_key + "&forUsername=" +name + "&part=id"
            r=requests.get(string) 
            data=json.loads(r.text)
            chan_id_list= data["items"][0]
            chan_id = chan_id_list["id"]
            return chan_id
        def is_live(self,channels_id):
            string = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId="+ channels_id+ "&type=video&eventType=live&key=" + self.api_key
            r=requests.get(string)
            data = json.loads(r.text)
            print data





    x=youtube()


    x.is_live(x.channel_id("WWE"))
    print x.channel_id("WWE")
```

When I run the code I get this output

```
{u'regionCode': u'US', u'kind': u'youtube#searchListResponse', u'etag': u'"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/-f6JA5_OcXz2RWuH1mpAA2_9mM8"', u'pageInfo': {u'resultsPerPage': 5, u'totalResults': 0}, u'items': []}

UC2Oxk5J24C1gYhDWpRDNPlw
```

I get a response but its empty. I feel like I'm missing something trivial. Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: are you sure you're supposed to call `x.channel_id("WWE")` twice? why not storing it in a variable?

Comment: I understand Jean, just writting code quickly. You are correct that would be the better style.

Comment: Maybe just not better style. Like this it perfotms 2 requests instead of one